# How would I scrape a series of pages where the element has a different xpath, using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I need some help scraping a series of pages like this: https://electionresults.ewashtenaw.org/electionreporting/aug2018/precinctreport1.html. The URLs are easy to sift through -- to get to the next page, you just higher the number after "precinctreport". I'm specifically trying to get only the vote totals for the second "Governor" section, with Abdul El-Sayed, Shri Thanedar, and Gretchen Whitmer. The issue is, I made my script with selenium using the first precinct page (the one I just linked), and the xpaths differ from page to page. So when I ran my script, it stopped at the second page because it couldn't find the element. How could I get around this?
Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#


# Finds the total number of precincts to be scraped 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/users/aliallam/Desktop/scraper test/chromedriver")
url = 'https://electionresults.ewashtenaw.org/electionreporting/aug2018/indexprecinctreport.html'
driver.get(url)
precinct_nums = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('regular')
driver.close()

# Perm vars
precincts = []
all_abdul_votes = []
all_shri_votes = []
all_gretchen_votes = []

def ScrapePrecinct(precinct):
    
    # Initial Selenium stuff
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/users/aliallam/Desktop/scraper test/chromedriver")
    url = f'https://electionresults.ewashtenaw.org/electionreporting/aug2018/precinctreport{precinct}.html'
    driver.get(url)

    # Find Precinct Name
    precinct_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name('h2').text

    # Find vote numbers for each candidate & assign to variable
    abdul_votes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[73]/td[4]').text
    shri_votes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[75]/td[4]').text
    gretchen_votes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[77]/td[4]').text
    
    # Append all data from precinct to perm vars 
    precincts.append(precinct_text)
    all_abdul_votes.append(abdul_votes)
    all_shri_votes.append(shri_votes)
    all_gretchen_votes.append(gretchen_votes)
   
    driver.quit()

iterations = len(precinct_nums)
counter = "1"
while int(counter) <= iterations:
    ScrapePrecinct(counter)
    counter = str(int(counter) + 1)

print(precincts)
print(all_abdul_votes)
print(all_shri_votes)
print(all_gretchen_votes)
```

Comment: please include one sample of desired output to make it easier for us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following xpaths should do the job:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/td[text()[contains(.,"Abdul El-Sayed(DEM)")]]/../td[4]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/td[text()[contains(.,"Shri Thanedar(DEM)")]]/../td[4]')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/td[text()[contains(.,"Gretchen Whitmer(DEM)")]]/../td[4]')
```

I have tried this on multiple 'precinctreport' pages and it seems to work fine.